# bash: mv file with apostrophe in file name

Tags: bash

I am trying to use `mv` to rename files. Some of the names of the files to be renamed contain apostrophes (or single quotes). And the file names are to be passed to `mv` with variables. But I cannot get that to work.

When I give the file names to `mv` directly, it does work, like that:

```
mv "Artificial intelligence/Markoff_Rosenberg__China's_intelligent_weaponry_gets_smarter.pdf" "Artificial intelligence/Markoff_Rosenberg__Chinas_intelligent_weaponry_gets_smarter_(r1205).pdf"
```

But when I use variables, it does not work:

```
orig="Artificial intelligence/Markoff_Rosenberg__China's_intelligent_weaponry_gets_smarter.pdf"
new="Artificial intelligence/Markoff_Rosenberg__Chinas_intelligent_weaponry_gets_smarter_(r1205).pdf"
mv "$orig" "$new"
```

I receive the following error message:

```
mv: cannot stat 'Artificial intelligence/Markoff_Rosenberg__China'\''s_intelligent_weaponry_gets_smarter.pdf': No such file or directory
```

Why is that? Why is there an extra `\''` in the file name in the error message? And what is the solution to the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You are getting this message since you have already renamed the file in your manual step! So first undo the rename and then run again using the variables. It WILL work.

Comment: @Rakesh: You are right. Stupid me! I thought that I had undone the rename before trying with the variables, but apparently I got confused with the various changes to the file names. And the extra `\''` in the file name in the error message threw me off. Thanks for the prompt reply! Should I delete the question, given that it turns out to be without general interest?

Comment: No don't delete the question, since for beginner's it might just be what the doctor ordered. This is similar to the scenario of computer not working when the power switch has not been turned ON. So before we go looking for exotic reasons to debug we need to first check the very basics.